# ANTLR - Parser definition & dealing with Left Recursion

Tags: parsing, recursion, antlr, lexer

Been reading the ANTLR website and the definitive ANTLR 4 reference guide, am I right in thinking that this is the definition of a Parser:

A Parser takes an input from a token stream generated by a lexer and applies a grammatical structure to it

and also I've been reading about Left recursion, does this get dealt with in the lexer and parser or just the lexer

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR 4 uses essentially the same ALL(*) mechanism for both parser and lexer, but ANTLR only rewrites left recursion in the parser (to be non-left recursive).